# The best scenario for app development to connect two or more devices over TCP/IP.

Tags: android, sockets, networking, tcp

I use web service for normal works. Worked with wifi and bluetooth networking. WiFI networking is very attractive, but it limit to local network and as I understood can not use to connect to remote IP. So what is the best fastest way to connect two or more devices on internet TCP/IP protocol? Any scenario is welcomed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you wish to do with connected devices. However following can be explored

> GCM
>
> Network of users(like any social network)
>
> Multiplayer Game Engine

Of these the GCM happens to be the fastest and the the one with least overhead.